GraalVM JS embedding with Uber Jar from Gradle
I am trying to integrate graalvm-js into my java application. I found the polyglot embedding demo: https://github.com/graalvm/polyglot-embedding-demo
I set it up and using the mavin assembly plugin I was able to build an uber jar that works correctly:
$ java -jar target/embedding-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Initializing language js
Hello JavaScript!

Now when I try to do the same with Gradle instead of Maven I run into a lot of problems. Even when I get it to execute the assemble task fully, when I try to run it I get the following error:
java -jar build/libs/embedding-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine.getImpl(Engine.java:442)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$Builder.build(Engine.java:740)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context$Builder.build(Context.java:1925)
    at org.example.embedding.Main.main(Main.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Polyglot version compatibility check failed.
The polyglot version '24.0.1' is not compatible to the used Truffle version '23.1.1'.
The Truffle or language version is older than the polyglot version in use.
The polygot and truffle version must always match.
Update the Truffle or language versions to '24.0.1' to resolve this.
To disable this version check the '-Dpolyglotimpl.DisableVersionChecks=true' system property can be used.
It is not recommended to disable version checks.

    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine.loadAndValidateProviders(Engine.java:1689)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$1.run(Engine.java:1735)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$1.run(Engine.java:1727)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine.initEngineImpl(Engine.java:1727)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$ImplHolder.<clinit>(Engine.java:190)
    ... 4 more

This is the build.gradle.kts file that I came up with after some tinkering:
import java.nio.file.*

plugins {
    id("java")
    id("application")
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
description = "embedding"

var graalVMVersion: String = "24.0.1";
dependencies {
    implementation("org.graalvm.polyglot:polyglot:$graalVMVersion")
    implementation("org.graalvm.polyglot:js:$graalVMVersion")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("org.example.embedding.Main")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnit()
}

tasks {
    withType<com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar> {
        archiveClassifier.set("")
        manifest {
            attributes(mapOf("Main-Class" to "org.example.embedding.Main"))
        }
    }
    
    build {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }

    distZip {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }

    distTar {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }

    startScripts {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }

    build {
        dependsOn(shadowJar)
    }

    named("startShadowScripts") {
        dependsOn(named("jar"))
    }
}


Note that before I used the ShadowJar plugin I used the basic "Jar" task without much success:
tasks.withType<Jar> {

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "org.example.embedding.Main"
    }

    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })

    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}

Of course without bundling it into an uber jar at all, simply running gradle clean run works as well, but I need to build a fat jar, as my application depends on that.
Any help is appreciated.

I believe (and may be very wrong) that the shadow plugin may be causing some issues here by fiddling with package names? The only way I was able to get it to work was by removing the shadow plugin and tweaking the Jar task slightly:
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter{!it.path.endsWith("pom")}.map {
        if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it)
    })
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "org.example.embedding.Main"
//        This works without the other stuff above, but is not helpful because this points to .gradle paths, making the fat jar non-portable
//        attributes["Class-Path"] = configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().joinToString(separator = " ")
    }
}

Some key differences that seem to make this one work:

duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE because we can't clobber
Remove dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath) because any classpath stuff at build time will likely be invalid)
.filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") } - we can include more than jars, but not poms


Unfortunately I get the same error again: The polyglot version '24.0.1' is not compatible to the used Truffle version '23.1.1'.
